# Merge subscription behaviour

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, merge-replication

I have a merge subscription with the ExchangeType parameter set to 1 (upload only).
Rows are transferred to the publisher as expected.

If I delete a row at the subscriber, the corresponding row at the publisher doesn't get deleted. Accidentally, this is the exact behaviour I desire, but I can't find any documentation stating it's by design.

Before going live, I would like to have something documenting the thing.

Can anyone confirm this is the expected behaviour?

Comment: What is the command you used to set up this scenario? I'm having a hard time tracking down anything in the documentation that allows this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the confusion. I missed an option in the article that decides how DELETEs are treated.

The option is called "delete_tracking" and it's set to 0. It is documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms174329.aspx